# Address of a static variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a simple class to unique ID conversion. I am thinking about adding a static method:

```
class A {
  static int const *GetId() {
    static int const id;
    return &id;
  }
};
```

Each class would then be identified by unique `int const *`. Is this guaranteed to work? Will the returned pointer really be unique? Is there any better simpler solution?

I have also thought about pointer to `std::type_info`:

```
class A {
  static std::type_info const *GetId() {
    return &typeid(A);
  }
};
```

Is that better?

**Edit:**

I don't need to use the id for serialization. I only want to identify a small set of base classes and I want all subclasses of some class to have the same id

Comment: Why not use RTTI instead of this hack?

Comment: @RedX: Because I want only id of a few base classes not the real object type.

Comment: Maybe you ought to outline what you intend to do with this - there could be better approaches?

Comment: Is this in the end used via a virtual interface? If not i don't see why you couldn't use a template-based compile time solution in the first place.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: CompileTime solution would be nice, but I need to store the objects in a Map so I need to map the type to some id.

Comment: If you would add a simplified version of what you're trying to do, there may be better alternatives. Without it it's too much guessing around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have noticed at least MSVC 2008 or 2010 optimizes the static variable, so that the following `GetId` function returns same address even for different classes.

```
static int const *GetId() {
    static const int i = 0;
    return &i;
}
```

Therefore address of uninitialized constant static variable may not be used for identification. The simplest fix is to just remove `const`:

```
static int *GetId() {
    static int i;
    return &i;
}
```

Another solution to generate IDs, that seems to work, is to use a global function as a counter:

```
int Counter() {
    static int i = 0;
    return i++;
}
```

And then define the following method in the classes to be identified:

```
static int GetId() {
    static const int i = Counter();
    return i;
}
```

As the method to be defined is always the same, it may be put to a base class:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Identified {
    static int GetId() {
        static const int i = Counter();
        return i;
    }
};
```

And then use a curiously recurring pattern:

```
class A: public Identified<A> {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Your first function should not compile: an uninitialized constant is not allowed in C++.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Fixed, but MSVC seems to allow uninitialized constants.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this will work. Each `static` local will be given distinct memory location at the time when the module is loaded and it will persist until the module is unloaded. Remember, `static` locals are stored in static storage that is distributed during compilation and they persist till the module gets unloaded, so they will have distinct memory locations.

Comment: His second suggestion is not guaranteed to work (although it's hard to imagine an implementation where it wouldn't).

Comment: When I unload a DLL and reload the same DLL, all the static addresses seem to be the same as they were before.  Do you know if this is observed behavior is risky to rely on?  (I'm only using for debugging purposes, for hot reloading.  And obviously if I change the static var layout, I have to fully restart.)

Answer (score 7):

The address of static variable is guaranteed to be unique and the same in all translation units.

It is not a good idea because it requires you to add code to every class to be identified.

The pointers to type info objects are not guaranteed to be unique, but the type info objects themselves are guaranteed to compare as equal for a given class, and as unequal for distinct classes. This means you can use small wrapper objects that carry  type info pointers, and the delegate the comparisions to the type info objects. C++11 has such a wrapper in the standard library, and if you don't have access to that, there is one in Andrei Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ Design", and therefore probably also in the Loki library, there is probably one in Boost, and there is one on my Wordpress blog  – it's not like you to have invent one from scratch.

If, however, the id's are to be used for serialization, then you need id's that are valid across builds. And in that case you you need strings or UUIDs. I would go with UUIDs.

To associate a class with an UUID you can in general use a type traits class. Or if you're only doing Windows programming then you can use Visual C++'s language extensions for this. I think but I am not 100% sure that those language extensions are also implemented by g++ (in Windows).

Cheers & hth.

Comment: It is not for serialization. I only want to identify a small set of base classes and I want all subclasses of some class to have the same id.

Comment: @Juraj: the requirements are baffling. In order to use your static member function you do need to know the class already. Unless this is template based code?

Comment: When you say the pointers to `type_info` objects are not guaranteed to be unique, I think you mean that they are not guaranteed to be the same; in practice, I think that for any given call site, they will be the same, but the standard doesn't guarantee it (and they can definitely be different at different call sites, but that's not an issue here).

Comment: How would you get a UUID per class that's persistent over builds/runs?

Comment: @Georg: you generate it once. and associate it once. that's the point of UUIDs, what they're designed for.

Comment: Ah, you meant manually associating them with a UUID, the type traits made me think of a generic approach.

Comment: @Georg COM has been doing this for more than 15 yrs now using the uuid attribute although its a compiler specific extension.

Comment: @dil: ... which also requires specifying an UUID manually, not generating a persistent one for you automatically. I'd still love to have something like that to reduce the possibilities of making mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The address of the static `int` is guaranteed to be unique for each
function (and the same for every call to the same function).  As such,
it can work very well as an id within a single execution of the code.
The address could conceivably change from one run to the next, and will
often change from one compilation to the next (if you've changed
anything in the code), so it is not a good solution for an external id.
(You don't say whether the id must be valid outside a single execution
or not.)

The address of the results of a `typeid` is not guaranteed to be the
same each time you call the function (although it probably will be). 
You could use it to initialize a pointer, however:

```
static std::type_info const& GetId()
{
    static std::type_info const* id = &typeid(A);
    return id;
}
```

Compared to using `int*`, this has the advantage of providing additional
information (e.g. for debugging).  Like `int*`, the identifier may be
different from one run to the next; `A::GetId()->name()` will point to
the same `'\0'` terminated string (although again the address might be
different) provided you compile with the same compiler.  (As far as I
can tell, the standard doesn't guarantee this, but in practice, I think
you're safe.)  Change compilers, however, and all bets are off.

The solution I've used in the past is something like:

```
static char const* GetId()
{
    return "A";  //  Or whatever the name of the class is.
}
```

This provides a unique identifier, easily compared, within a single
execution of the code, and a string value which can be used as an
external identifier, and which is guaranteed across all compilers.  We
implemented this as a macro, which defined both the static function, and
a virtual function which returned it, e.g.:

```
#define DECLARE_IDENTIFIER(name)                                    \
    static char const* classId() { return STRINGIZE(name); }        \
    virtual char const* id() { return classId(); }
```

This results in a very fast (but limited) RTTI, and supports external
identifiers for serialization and persistency.

Comment: Hm, that macro would still allow for unintentional duplicates, e.g. two people using `Foo` for both `A::Foo` and `B::Foo`.

Comment: Yes.  You'd have to set coding standards, e.g. that the name included the namespace.  But it's the simplest solution I know not involving machine generated code which gives reliable external identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The int* method would be unique, since a different static memory cell must be allocated for each static variable, and I'd guess it is simpler to understandthan the type_info idea.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly pointers to different variables must have different values. Just watch out if you choose to derive a subclass of A. You need to decide what your policy is for id. If you did nothing then the subclass would have the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are initialized before Heap & Stack memory so yeah it will be unique.

Quirky though.

Comment: It's a function-local static variable, not a static member variable.

Comment: It doesn't matter about initialisation, the variable is not initialised and it doesn't matter. Only its address is taken and this is determined at compile / dyld time.

Comment: Well their memory are allocated at compiler time (more or less) so OK you should read "the memory location is initialized" as it is what the OP is using, the location not the value. Anyway there are 100 answers now, mine doesn't really matter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you really really want to avoid hacky things like this.  If I really had to do this, I'd look at using some UUID system (there's a library in Boost for that, but I'm not very familiar with it), or some singleton that maintained a list of these objects for whatever purpose you need.

Comment: We may live in a different world, but I do not find anything hacky about this. Sometimes it is useful (and it is a lot lighter than full RTTI implementation, which sometimes you may need to disable).

Comment: ... and I do not see anything wrong with anonymous downvotes. :(

Comment: Very occasionally they could be useful, but it can allow just so many bugs to creep in.For example, say you wanted to now serialise this class. It would seem to all work, and perhaps even it would keep on working until you add another static in somewhere, or change some other unrelated part of the code. Suddenly, all your serialisation code stops working, just because the address of that static variable has changed.

Answer (score -2):

Because you will have to add this method to all classes that require a UID you may as well do this.

```
unsigned int getUID()
{
    return 12;
}
```

The advantage of this is that the compiler will be able to use a jump table if you are using this for RTTI for switching on type, which will not be possible with two pointers because the jump table would be very sparse.

The (minor) disadvantage is you need to keep track of which identifiers have been taken.

A major disadvantage of the first method you presented is that the same numbers cannot be used to identify objects because the virtual getUID() method won't be able to take the address of the variable in another function's scope.

Comment: Having to manage the enumerations manually is not feasible: Why allow for mistakes to happen if you can prevent them in the first place?

Comment: You can allocate them using a incrementing count. Saved in a file somewhere. Working in a team you can have each person hold a lock on the file to add a UID preventing concurrency issues.