# Why can static local object be accessed via pointer or reference from outside?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As you may know, a local static variable cannot be accessed outside the function by name but can be accessed via pointer or reference to it. So the code below is well-formed.

But why? I know this fact as a fact, but have no ground. Actually what I want is **the related excerpt from C++ standard**. I'm reading it but not end up finding the evidence. Could anyone please give me the excerpt or a hint to find that (because just searching "static" in the document results in over a hundred of hits)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {

    public:

        int * f(int i) const {
            static int j;
            j += i;
            cout << "now j = " << j << "\n";
            return &j;
        }

        int & g(int i) const { //same as above but handle reference
            static int k;
            k += i;
            cout << "now k = " << k << "\n";
            return k;
        }

};

int main() {

    Test t;

    int *p = t.f(3); //=> "now j = 3"
    *p += 10;
    t.f(0); //=> "now j = 13"

    int &r = t.g(3); //=> "now k = 3"
    r += 10;
    t.g(0); //=> "now k = 13"

}
```

I took a look at all of the about 20 questions suggested by stack overflow, but have no answer yet. (There was only one related question: [Can I access static variables inside a function from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635953/can-i-access-static-variables-inside-a-function-from-outside).)

---

For the future readers (or just my note):

As indicated in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213960/why-can-static-local-object-be-accessed-via-pointer-or-reference-from-outside#comment97163796_55213960), the same applies to the case of a class member even if it is distant and `private`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    private:
        int i = 0;
    public:
        int * return_pointer() { return &i; }
        void print() { cout << "i = " << i << "\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        int * return_pointer() { return Base::return_pointer(); }
};

int main() {

    Derived d;
    d.print(); //=> "i = 0"

    int *p = d.return_pointer();
    *p = 300;
    d.print(); //=> "i = 300"

}
```

Comment: Other related questions: [Address of a static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525942/address-of-a-static-variable), [Is returning a pointer to a static local variable safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453696/is-returning-a-pointer-to-a-static-local-variable-safe)

Comment: What do you expect the standard to say about using a pointer or reference that *happens* to refer to a static local?  The scope and linkage rules affect *names*, and the return value of `f` or `g` has no name at all.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453730/68587) summarizes it well: "Static variables in a function are like scoped global variables." They're lexically inaccessible from the outside, but their storage duration is the same as global variables so their address is valid for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: It's just a case of "you can access objects that exist"  , there is no special case for static or class member or whatever,  you won't find any more specific language beyond the description of reading an object's value

Comment: Thank you for all. Now it seems the behavior is natural.

Comment: From a textbook: "Static  objects  inside functions  are  known  as  local  static  objects  (because  they’re  local  to  a function),  and  the  other  kinds  of  static  objects  are  known  as  non-local static  objects.  Static  objects  are  destroyed  when  the  program  exits, i.e.,  their  destructors  are  called  when  main  finishes  executing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant quotes from the C++17 standard (n4659) tell us about the storage duration of `static` variables:

> **6.7.1 Static storage duration [basic.stc.static]**
>   1 All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have static storage duration. **The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the program** (6.6.2, 6.6.4).
>   ...
>   3 The keyword `static` can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duration. [ Note: 9.7 describes the initialization of local static variables; 6.6.4 describes the destruction of local static variables. —end note ]

The lifetime of `static` variables local to a function begins the first time the program flow encounters the declaration and it ends at program termination.

As mentioned in the comments there is no direct quote which says that such variables can be accessed via pointer or reference.

However the following quote from **`[basic.life]`** (while not directly applicable to your scenario) tells something about using pointers to objects whose storage is still valid (allocated but not released or reused) but whose lifetime has not started or already ended:

> 6 Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or destruction, see 15.7.
>   **Otherwise, such a pointer refers to allocated storage, and using the pointer as if the pointer were of type `void*`, is well-defined**. Indirection through such a pointer is permitted but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways, as described below. The program has undefined behavior if:
>   (6.1) — the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor and the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression,
>   (6.2) — the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or
>   (6.3) — the pointer is implicitly converted to a pointer to a virtual base class, or
>   (6.4) — the pointer is used as the operand of a static_cast, except when the conversion is to pointer to `cv void`, or to pointer to `cv void` and subsequently to pointer to `cv char, cv unsigned char`, or `cv std::byte`, or
>   (6.5) — the pointer is used as the operand of a `dynamic_cast`.